# Will Google Play automatically publish to production when promoting a closed testing track?

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I have an app that is already published to a Close Testing track. Now I am about to promote it to Production however I still don't want it to be published to the public Play store yet. Now the question is will clicking on "Promote Release > Production" automatically publish the app to the public Play store or will it allow me to select when to Publish the app?

Note: I have already turned on the Manage Publishing feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, clicking on "Promote Release > Production" will publish the app to the public Google Play store.

You can read more about application publishing here: [Prepare and roll out a release](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859348?hl=en)

Comment: So just to confirm, I dont actually have to go through the review process again right when I promote from closed testing to production?

Comment: As I remember, yes. But it may be changed now because Google Play updated their console and some processes with app publishing.

Comment: Okay, apparently after you promote it, it doesn't automatically get published. It will still go through the Google review first. Only after it has been reviewed, then we can choose when to publish it.

Comment: @AlvinTandian does the review after promoting to production takes the same time as the first review in closed track? Or it shorter because its already reviewed at first upload?

Comment: @AlvinTandian how to choose when to publish it? As far as I know if we're publishing our app to production for the first time, there's only a 'start rollout to production' button and that will submit the app to be reviewed and once reviewed it gets published immediately..

Comment: My app that I promoted from Internal Testing to Open Testing (unlimited users) was reviewed and set to live after 2 days. And I did not see any comments by the reviewer. I read conflicting answers regarding a new review process when promoting to Production.  Can I assume it will be accepted for review if I promote it from Open Testing to Production without any change to the app?

Comment: @unice do you now have the answer to your question?

Comment: @unice The Production review will be shorter since the build has already been reviewed.